# Load immediate direct

Tags: cpu-architecture

[image]

Can teach how to do this question?
explain how to use load immediate, direct, indirect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Check Wikipedia's entry on [addressing modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode).

Basically, a **load immediate** (or **load literal**) will write the number that is contained inside the instruction into the accumulator. E.g. **load immediate 5** will place a 5 in the accumulator. `accumulator:=5`

A **load direct** will read memory at the address that is contained inside the instruction and place the result in the accumulator. E.g. **load direct 5** will read the memory at address 5 and write the result to the accumulator. If contents of memory at address `x` are designated as `memory(address:x)` then `accumulator:=memory(address:5)`

A **load indirect** will read memory twice. It reads memory at the address that is contained inside the instruction, and then it reads memory another time at the address that was indicated by the first memory location and writes the result in the accumulator. E.g. **load indirect 5** will read the memory at the address 5. Let's say that memory location 5 contains a 10. Then, in the second step, the processor will read memory location 10 and place the result in the accumulator. `accumulator:=memory(address:memory(address:5))`